# Fragmento com TABS dentro de outro fragmento com AppCompat

Tags: android, android-fragment

É possivel adicionar um fragmento com TABS ([HORIZONTAL VIEW SWIPING WITH TABS](http://just-another-blog.net/programming/how-to-implement-horizontal-view-swiping-with-tabs/)) dentro de outro fragmneto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema com esta adaptação:

```html
public class FragListaJogos extends Fragment{
 private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter; 
 private ViewPager mViewPager;  
 private View view;
 private FragmentActivity myContext;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
   @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_jogos, container, false);
  mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());
  mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);  
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
  return view;  
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
     super.onAttach(activity);
 }
 
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  
    
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
            super(fm);  
        }  
  
        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.  
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class  
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.  
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();  
            Bundle args = new Bundle();  
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);  
            fragment.setArguments(args);  
            return fragment;  
        }  
  
        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            // Show 3 total pages.  
            return 3;  
        }  
  
        @Override  
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {  
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();  
            switch (position) {  
            case 0:  
                return ("Teste1").toUpperCase(l);  
            case 1:  
                return ("Teste2").toUpperCase(l);  
            case 2:  
                return ("Teste3").toUpperCase(l);  
            }  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  
  
    /** 
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply 
     * displays dummy text. 
     */  
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {  
        /** 
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this 
         * fragment. 
         */  
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";  
  
        public DummySectionFragment() {  
        }  
  
        @Override  
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_jogos, container, false);  

            return rootView;  
        }  
    }  
  
 

}
```

Basicamente eu dei um Override no método onAttach desta forma:

```html
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
     myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
     super.onAttach(activity);
 }
```